# how to add a percent symbol to a string value output from sql query

Tags: php, sql, css, video

This is probably more simple than I think, but I'm having a really hard time wrapping my head around this. I've been trying to learn how to code after a 10 year hiatus from it, so hacking and codecademy are my teachers. Anyways, ...

What I'm trying to do is simply make a whole number from an sql entry a percentage.

I have a form which when submitted enters an sql value whole number that is used to output a css value. I'm only trying to **change the width value from a whole number to a percentage** to allow some semblance for a responsive effect.

Here's the php pre-output:

```
        <video id="vp2_html5_rightSidePlaylist_'.$row["id"].'" width="'.$row["playerWidth"].'%" height="'.$row["playerHeight"].'" '.$preload_aux.'><div class="xplaylist">'.$playlist_str.'</div></video>
```

The output is as follows:

```
        <video id="vp2_html5_rightSidePlaylist_1" width="100" height="297" preload="auto" src="http://localhost:888/test.mp4">
```

Thanks in advance for any help!

Comment: Hi @user1951749, welcome to stack overflow. Great question. Hope the answers are helping.

Answer (score 2):

If you are using mysql, you could use the [`CONCAT()` function](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en//string-functions.html#function_concat) to add some character to the end of a specific field.

> **`CONCAT(str1,str2,...)`** - Returns the string that results from concatenating the arguments.

For example -

```
SELECT `id`,`title`,CONCAT(`percentage`,'%') as percentage FROM `items` LIMIT 100
```

Now, what ever value was stored in the `percentage` field will have a `%` character appended to it in the result set.

Comment: I like this idea, but unfortunately I'm not as well versed with how to implement it. Little insight as to which document/where would be great! Thanks for the help!

Comment: @can - there is a link in the first line of my answer. It leads to the mysql documentation. IMO they explain best over there. Bassicaly you use `CONCAT()` to manipulate strings in an SQL statement. Whatever the value in a field is, it'll append or prepend anything you want. Inthis case, all you are looking for is the percentage character `%`.

Comment: Apologies for wasting your time, but a little help about how to run the SQL query in phpMyAdmin would be great. When running your code (with `percentage` replaced with `playerWidth`), I get the following error "Table 'wordpress.items' doesn't exist". What should `items` be?

Comment: @can - the SQL I gave you was just pseudo code. I don't actually know how your database is structured or what the table names are. I didn't even know you were using Wordpress :P `items` is the table that you are extracting the information from. Your percentage value (playerWidth) should be stored in that table (whatever it's name is).

Comment: Well the CONCAT() ran perfectly in phpMyAdmin! But oddly enough, that percentage value isn't being appended whence the plugin loads... Again, totally appreciate your help. You have definitely taught me a few things! :D Unfortunately I think I'll have to rethink this plugin...

Comment: @can - Happy to help! but what plugin? :S

Comment: It's a premium shortcode plugin that has a video playlist wp admin interface to upload and organize playlists. Unfortunately the author has explicitly said he won't help mod it to be responsive... That's a pretty low blow, but understandable since I'm hacking it. If you're interested in the challenge, I've been looking for someone to help... So far a few local coders have declined since it's been out of their knowledge base. Even with in$entive! haha

Answer (score 2):

I guess this is not an issue of your coding.

May I assume that you got this:

```
<video id="vp2_html5_rightSidePlaylist_1" width="100" height="297" preload="auto" src="http://localhost:888/test.mp4">
```

..via a tool like firebug/developer-tools?

When yes, this is not the original source, there has been  a cleanup of invalid parts.

One of them is the percent-sign, it's not valid inside the width-attribute. To get the desired result, use css instead:

```
'style="width:'.$row["playerWidth"].'%;height:'.$row["playerHeight"].'px;"'
```

Comment: Good catch. Most other answers tried to force the % symbol into the string from MySQL, which would work, but would not solve the problem.

Comment: Thanks Dr.Molle! Unfortunately this isn't working... The output isn't placing the all important % character. I failed to mention this previously, but this is being output as part of wordpress shortcode. My method of entering the % is currently by placing it into the php of the plugin layout, which I'm sure would work. Does this help?

Answer (score 0):

Use this:

```
Select CONCAT(`playerWidth`,'%') AS playerWidth, id .....etc FROM tableName
```

Comment: I like this idea, but unfortunately I'm not as well versed with how to implement it. Little insight as to which document/where would be great! Thanks for the help!